# Makefile: what does $@~ mean?

Tags: makefile

I am working on an old makefile that contains the following snippet to generate a shared library:

```
lib$(LIBNAME).so.$(SOLIBREV): $(OBJS)
    $(RM) $@~
    @SONAME=`echo $@ | sed 's/\.[^\.]*$$//'`; set -x; \
    $(CC) -o ./$@~ -shared -Wl,-soname,$$SONAME $(OBJS) $(SOEXTRALIBS) -lc;
    $(MV) $@~ $@
    $(MV) $@ lib$(LIBNAME).so
```

Now I need to modify that. I know that $@ specifies the target but what meaning does the tilde in "$@~" have?

By the way SOLIBREV stands for so-library-revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything special.  It's just `$@` followed by a literal `~`.  A `~` suffix on filenames is often used for temporary files, so this recipe is using a temporary file named after the target but with the extra `~` suffix.